when i am clicking button on flutter screen app also api is hitting ,but on my terminal nothing is print and not showing any changes
\`void initState() {
settoken();
print("=dateOrPartnerCollection==\>${GlobalData.getdateOrPartnerCollection()}");
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); //! inwidget

_localStreamController.stream.listen((event)=>print(event)); Fir        ebaseFirestore.instance.collection(GlobalData.getdateOrPartnerCollection()).snapshots().listen((QuerySnapsho       t querySnapshot) =>_localStreamController.add(querySnapshot));generateProfileIdList();
super.initState();

> > -              my code is working properly but for debugging if I want to print      any thing on terminal its not   print or      getting changes after using this screen of can I    solve this . I am using android 

# \> \> - \`\`\`


Try to print something before calling settoken() in initState.
